# stored procedure for different databases

Tags: sql-server

Can I use a stored procedure to select records from different databases (in SQL)?  I have a table from each database and I want to join them.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as long as you have permissions.  You can also do cross server if you have a [Linked Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/linked-servers-database-engine) setup.

Cross DB Example:

```
SELECT * FROM localTable as lt
INNER JOIN otherDB.dbo.OtherTable as ot
ON lt.ID = ot.id
```

Cross Server example (assumes you have created the linked server):

```
SELECT * FROM localTable as lt
INNER JOIN ServerName.otherDB.dbo.OtherTable as ot
ON lt.ID = ot.id
```

Comment: hrm, okay.  The databases are on the different sever and I do not have the linked server. I guess I can't really do this then.

Comment: @Tony If your data lives on different servers then you will either have to build a linked server or move the data. Don't know anything about your environment but we have a set of jobs that replicate a small portion of our warehouse data back out to the app servers nightly so that we have access to some common data (client lists etc.) in all of our apps without having to rekey things or having linked servers all over the place. We use SSIS to move the data around.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Just use 3 part naming syntax `database_name.schema_name.table_name`.

You also need to either enable cross database ownership chaining. (Not recommended) or use [this approach.](http://facility9.com/2008/09/30/avoiding-cross-database-ownership-chaining)

Answer (score 1):

Use the fully qualified table name. e.g, If you are in database ABC and want to access table table in database XYZ, access it as `XYZ.dbo.table`
(It could be dbo or something else depending on the owner of the table. Usually it is dbo)

Comment: Should note that the Schema and Owner have not been the same thing since SQL Server 2005. In many of our app databases we use schemas to differentiate user data from the apps metadata. In our warehouse environments we use schemas to identify related tables/procs so that we can easily apply security to the group of objects. I rarely see them used to identify the object owners.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like the following:

```
SELECT a.userID, b.usersFirstName 
FROM databaseA.dbo.TableA a 
INNER JOIN database B.dbo.TableB b ON a.userID = b.userID
```

Source: http://forums.asp.net/t/1254974.aspx

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it! If you post error messages, **please** use the blockquotes ( ` " ` ) to properly format the error message.

Answer (score 0):

One other technique that works better in some environments is to define a synonym for the remote table.  This lets you have a local reference that points to the remote object.  Particularly useful if you are in an environment where you have to migrate things and the relative locations may not be the same from one environment to the next.  Here is a quick overview:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/01/07/sql-server-2005-introduction-and-explanation-to-synonym-helpful-t-sql-feature-for-developer/